# CSS hover & position: absolute not working

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I know this question has been asked a few times but none of the answers were very clear, I have written some basic code if someone could solve the code and explain why this problem happens, it would be much appreciated. The problem is `.hover` animation is canceled when the position is set to absolute on the footer.

https://codepen.io/HamHat/pen/zpemYz

And here is the code for future use, which seems to be a common problem.

HTML:

```
<footer>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#privacy">Privacy</a></li>
  </ul>
      <div class="bear">
      <a href="google.com"><img src="https://placebear.com/g/80/80"></a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer{
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

ul{
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

li a{
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover{
  background-color: white;
}

.bear {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bear image width was 100% thats why it was not working

```css
footer{
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

ul{
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

li a{
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
  background-color: white;
}

.bear {
  width : 10%;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#privacy">Privacy</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="bear">
      <a href="google.com"><img src="https://placebear.com/g/80/80"></a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you, a simple fix and a simple answer!